# render json data in index

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I dont understand why this is not working. Sometimes I can get the first object from the json file and as soon as i want a nested object it fails to fetch it.

How do i make it render the "album_cover" text ?

I am using express js.

my index.js in routing folder

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

var fs = require('fs');



/* GET home page. */

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

var file = __dirname + '/../public/list/list.json';


fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {

if (err) {

  console.log('Error: ' + err);

  return;

}


data = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(data);

res.render('index', { title: data });

});

});


module.exports = router;
```

and here is my json file.

```
{
  "Year": {
    "2011": {
      "top40": {
        "id": {
          "01": {
            "album_cover": "http://o.scdn.co/image/830a22646bc38f72df95ec98e3ab6bb19aa6074b",
        "artist namn": "Adele",
        "song": "Rolling In The Deep",
        "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/track/7h8Ud480Fm4ReUVxgFF9ZX",
        "youtube": "http://youtu.be/rYEDA3JcQqw"
      },
      "02": {
        "album_cover": "http://o.scdn.co/image/215c999786e8319a09b7af87a970c2bdb6747c92",
        "artist namn": "LMFAO",
        "song": "Party Rock Anthem",
        "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/track/1CNJyTUh56oj3OCZOZ5way",
        "youtube": "http://youtu.be/KQ6zr6kCPj8"
      }
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

and here is my index view file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>

<h1>Top Hits year : :<%= title %></h1>
<h2>Adele<%= title %></h2>
<p>Rolling In The Deep <%= title %></p>
  <a href="http://open.spotify.com/track/7h8Ud480Fm4ReUVxgFF9ZX " target="_blank"><img src="/images/spotify.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://youtu.be/rYEDA3JcQqw" target="_blank"><img src="/images/youtube.png"></a>
  </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I converted your object it gives me an error at `"2011"` because it is a number.

```
console.log(data.Year.2011);
```

I changed your json like

```
{
  "Year": {
    "top2011": {
      "top40": {
        "id": {
          "top01": {
            "album_cover": "http://o.scdn.co/image/830a22646bc38f72df95ec98e3ab6bb19aa6074b",
        "artist namn": "Adele",
        "song": "Rolling In The Deep",
        "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/track/7h8Ud480Fm4ReUVxgFF9ZX",
        "youtube": "http://youtu.be/rYEDA3JcQqw"
      },
      "top02": {
        "album_cover": "http://o.scdn.co/image/215c999786e8319a09b7af87a970c2bdb6747c92",
        "artist namn": "LMFAO",
        "song": "Party Rock Anthem",
        "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/track/1CNJyTUh56oj3OCZOZ5way",
        "youtube": "http://youtu.be/KQ6zr6kCPj8"
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

After this I am able to use it

```
console.log(data.Year.top2011.top40.id.top01.album_cover);
```

OR without changing your json you can use like

```
data.Year['2011']['top40']['id']['01']['album_cover']);

or

data.Year['2011'].top40.id['01'].album_cover
```

Comment: Okej, this worked, So in json file I cant use numbers as first character then ?

Comment: better if you start your key with character otherwise
 easy way is like
data['Year']['2011']['top40']['id']['01']['album_cover']);

Comment: I tried to iterate through the object with .forEach, but it keep saying that its not defind

Answer (score 0):

Your render method will have to look something like this if you want to access the first album_cover field:

```
res.render('index', { title: data.Year.2011.top40.id.01.album_cover });
```

Comment: Try like (data.Year['2011']));